# How to reuse if condition in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am having a two `if` condition . I want to reuse that for to use of less lines of code. I dont know how to reuse it. Pls share your suggestion. Here i am sharing the code.

```
if (mapData.drillLevel === 'area') {
  setShowBtn(true);
  getCitiesData(cityId);
  setViewport({
    ...viewport,
    latitude: lat,
    longitude: long,
    zoom: 6.5,
  });
}
if (mapData.drillLevel === 'city') {
  setShowBtn(false);
  getStatesData();
  setViewport({
    ...viewport,
    latitude: 19.83,
    longitude: 83.92,
    zoom: 4,
  });
}
```

I have done this using reactJS .

Comment: You could change this completely to introduce using a dictionary and then reference the values based on the element city or area

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch`

```
let latitude;
let lng;
let zoom;
switch(mapData.drillLevel) {
 case 'area':
    setShowBtn(true);
    getCitiesData(cityId);
    latitude = lat;
    ....
    break;
 case 'city':
     setShowBtn(false);
     getStatesData();
    latitude = 19.83;
    ....
    break;
}

setViewport({
  ...viewport,
  latitude: latitude,
  longitude: lng,
  zoom: zoom,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your values under the condition and call the functions later

```
let latitude, longitude, zoom;
if (mapData.drillLevel === 'area') {
     getCitiesData(cityId);
     latitude: 22.83; longitude: 88.92; zoom: 6.5;
} else if (mapData.drillLevel === 'city') {
     getStatesData();
     latitude: 19.83; longitude: 83.92; zoom: 4;
}
setShowBtn(mapData.drillLevel === 'area');
setViewport({
   ...viewport,
   latitude: latitude,
   longitude: 83.92,
   zoom: 4,
});
```